# "serverhit.com" seems to be a clone/scrapper of Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, clone

Website in question: http://www.serverhit.com/

Screenshot of ServerHit:

[image: Screenshot of ServerHit]

First question on ServerHit is taken from Ask Ubuntu:

[image: Screenshot of Ask Ubuntu for comparison]

I have already utilized the contact form, however, I am additionally submitting here for visibility.